# Is it good or ok or a bad practice to add Dependency via a RUN command in Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I am trying to create an image using a multi-stage build for a node project. I am using [NestJs](https://nestjs.com/) for the project since it uses TypeScript, and if I install only production dependency in the production stage it will not install NestJs CLI. Now, NestJs CLI is required to compile all the TypeScipt code to JavaScript. Most of the people or the blogs I have read, what they do is copy the output folder (compiled code from TypeScript to JavaScript) in the production stage which I don't want to do and really don't like the idea of copying the output folder because if I run only production stage via compose or a container it will fail.

Now, I have two options, either I can move the NestJs CLI as dependencies required for production in my package.json file, or I can add NestJs CLI via a RUN command in my Dockerfile, I want to know what would be right or the best way to do it.

I have asked this question devops.stackexchange.com but I have not got any answers.

Comment: The whole point of multi staging is precisely that you copy some type of artefact into the next stage. Why would you use multi staging if you are not using anything from the first stage in the second stage?  I dont understand what you mean by if you run production stage only with compose it fails. As it stands the question is opinion based and probably should get closed.

Comment: If you are using the stages like 2 separate builds, then you are doing it wrong. You should use separate Dockerfiles for that purpose. The word *Stage* implies that this is a sequential setup, those should not be treated as separate entities.

Comment: Use different setups for production and development. If that means different `Dockerfile`s or just different `docker-compose.yml` depends on what you need. Most of the time you don't need a `Dockerfile` at all for you dev setup (in my experience). Just bind-mount your project into a suitable `node` image. For production you want a multi-stage build that only captures the static output you need.

Comment: @TheFool, I agree the question is opinionated and I also agree with your point of multi-staging is precise that we copy some type of artifact into the next stage. Thank you, I guess I have my answer.